# Are there any methods included in Scala to convert tuples to lists?

Tags: scala, list, tuples

I have a `Tuple2` of `List[List[String]]` and I'd like to be able to convert the tuple to a list so that I can then use `List.transpose()`. Is there any way to do this? Also, I know it's a `Pair`, though I'm always a fan of generic solutions.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

Works with any tuple (scala 2.8):

```
myTuple.productIterator.toList
```

Scala 2.7:

```
(0 to (myTuple.productArity-1)).map(myTuple.productElement(_)).toList
```

---

Not sure how to maintain type info for a general Product or Tuple, but for Tuple2:

```
def tuple2ToList[T](t: (T,T)): List[T] = List(t._1, t._2)
```

You could, of course, define similar type-safe conversions for all the Tuples (up to 22).

Comment: Looks good, though you need `myTuple.productArity - 1` and `productElement()` returns an `Any`. Is there any way to maintain the inner type information.

Comment: Corrected indexing off-by-one and added type maintaining comment in answer.

Comment: productElements is deprecated, use myTuple.productIterator.toList instead

Comment: Answer edited to reflect latest version per Tommy Chheng's comment.

Comment: Just to be explicit: productIterator loses all type information and produces Any. In retrospect that is not surprising because feature of tuple is that each element can have unrelated type.

Answer (score 10):

Using Shapeless -

```
@ import syntax.std.tuple._
import syntax.std.tuple._
@ (1,2,3).toList
res21: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
@ (1,2,3,4,3,3,3,3,3,3,3).toList
res22: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3)
```

Note that type information is not lost using Shapeless's `toList`.