# Scala List of tuples to flat list

Tags: scala

I have list of tuple pairs, `List[(String,String)]` and want to flatten it to a list of strings, `List[String]`.

Comment: How would you go from two strings to a single string? We have no idea how you want to combine them.

Comment: not very scala those angle brackets...

Comment: well you have a tuple of 2 strings i.e. <"John, "Paul"> and after some flattening.... a List...."John", "Paul"

Comment: It's `List[(String, String)]` to denote a list of tuples that contain strings.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Some of the options might be:
concatenate:

```
list.map(t => t._1 + t._2)
```

one after the other interleaved (after your comment it seems you were asking for this):

```
list.flatMap(t => List(t._1, t._2))
```

split and append them:

```
list.map(_._1) ++ list.map(_._2)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the third option is quite inefficient: it traverses the same list twice, than appends a list to another, which has linear complexity.

Answer (score 10):

Well, you can always use flatMap as in:

```
list flatMap (x => List(x._1, x._2))
```

Although your question is a little vague.

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
val tt = List(("John","Paul"),("George","Ringo"))
tt.flatMap{ case (a,b) => List(a,b) }
```

This results in:

> List(John, Paul, George, Ringo)

Answer (score 3):

In general for lists of tuples of any arity, consider this,

```
myTuplesList.map(_.productIterator.map(_.toString)).flatten
```

Note the `productIterator` casts all types in a tuple to `Any`, hence we recast values here to `String`.

Answer (score 0):

See -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43716004/4610065

In this case -

```
import syntax.std.tuple._
List(("John","Paul"),("George","Ringo")).flatMap(_.toList)
```