# Tail-recursive implementation of in-shuffle

Tags: scala, recursion, shuffle, tail-recursion

I am using recursion for `In_Shuffle` the list passed to the method but getting confused with the recursion base case. Since Scala does not allow you to modify the parameter passed so i can not assign new value to the passed list. 
Here is my code:

```
def shuffle(list1: List[Any], list2: List[Any]): List[Any] = {
    list1.zipAll(list2, "", "")
      .flatMap(_.productIterator.toList)
      .filter(_ != "")
  }
```

```
def splitLists(list: List[Any], n: Int) = {
    if (n > list.length) {
      throw new Exception("N is greater than length of list")
    }
    else if (n == list.length) {
      List(list, List())
    }
    else {
      List(list.slice(0, n),
        list.slice(n, list.length))
    }
  }
```

Following method is in infinite loop. I know the problem is in the very first line where I am initializing the `list` variable.

```
  @annotation.tailrec
  def in_shuffle(list:List[Any], org_list:List[Any]):Any={
    var list:List[Any] = List()
    if (list.equals(org_list)) return true
    if (list.length<1) {
      list=org_list
    }
    val div_list = splitLists(list, list.length/2)
    list = shuffle(div_list(0), div_list(1))
    in_shuffle(list, org_list)
  }
```

`In-Shuffle` is getting called using the following code.

`println(in_shuffle(List(), (1 to 4).toList))`

 Any help will highly be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Array passed will be: [1,2,3,4]
`Step 1: [1,3,2,4] --> Divide equally and then perform Shuffling`
`Step 2: [1,2,3,4] --> Divide equally and then perform Shuffling `

Checks if its original list returns true.

Comment: I don't think it's very clear what you want to achieve and what the question is. "Getting confused with the base case"... how? where? what confuses you?

Comment: Please use generics instead of **Any**.

Comment: Please specify example input and output. I've missed something. It will help us to grab intention and simplify implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are few issues with your code. We try to avoid `Any` so instead of

```
def shuffle(list1: List[Any], list2: List[Any]): List[Any]
```

we use a type parameter `T`

```
def shuffle(t: (List[T], List[T])): List[T]
```

Next we [flatten a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27068021/5205022) like so

```
def shuffle(t: (List[T], List[T])): List[T] =
  t._2 zip t._1 flatMap { case (a, b) => List(a, b) }
```

Next we use out-of-the-box [`splitAt`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#splitAt(n:Int):(List[A],List[A])) instead of rolling our own `splitLists`

```
val (left, right) = list.splitAt(list.size/2)
```

Finally we avoid using `return`. Putting it all together we have

```
def in_shuffle[T](original: List[T]) = {
  require(original.size % 2 == 0, "In shuffle requires even number of elements")

  def shuffle(t: (List[T], List[T])): List[T] =
    t._2 zip t._1 flatMap { case (a, b) => List(a, b) }

  def midpoint(l: List[T]): Int = l.size / 2

  @annotation.tailrec def loop(current: List[T]): Boolean = {
    if (original == current) true
    else loop(shuffle(current.splitAt(midpoint(current))))
  }

  loop(shuffle(original.splitAt(midpoint(original))))
}

in_shuffle((1 to 52).toList)   // res0: Boolean = true
```

Note [in shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_shuffle) requires number of elements to be even.

Comment: One question @mario. What if we need to switch to out-shuffle??????

Comment: @petereg157 Just switch `t._2 zip t._1` around to `t._1 zip t._2`